# Test Axon aggregate's behaviour with non-aggregate events

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, axon

I'm trying to ensure an aggregate field is unique on creation. I'm trying to handle the eventually consistency of the projections by using the following flow:

1. Command creates a new aggregate
2. Aggregate issues creation event
3. Event handler attempts to materialize the projection and if there is a uniqueness violation, it emits a `UniqueConstraintViolationEvent`
4. Aggregate consumes this event and marks itself as deleted

I'm trying to use the `AggregateTestFixture` to test this, but it doesn't appear to allow you to preform any assertions without issuing a command (`whenThenTimeElapses` seems to allow assertions, but I get a NPE when asserting the aggregate has been deleted). Is there a way to use the test fixture for this case, or is it not designed to account for non-aggregate events. If not, is there another way to verify that the aggregate has been removed?

I'm not confident that this is actually the correct approach. I've also considered dispatching a command in (3) or using a saga to manage the interaction. If I dispatch a command instead of an event, it seems to simply force me to write more boilerplate to emit the `UniqueConstraintViolationEvent` from the aggregate. Likewise, if I use a saga to model this interaction, I'm unsure how to end the saga's lifecycle without having the projection materializer emit a success event that the saga consumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at a Set Based Validation scenario, which is a little more cumbersome when dealing with a CQRS system. This [blog](https://danielwhittaker.me/2017/10/09/handle-set-based-consistency-validation-cqrs/) explains some of your options nicely I feel, thus I'd pick and choose from there.

As a form of guideline, note that the Aggregate guards **it's own** consistency boundary. Extending that boundary by asserting uniqueness among an entire set of Aggregate is thus not desirable. Simply put, not a single Aggregate instance's problem.

Hence, I would perform this uniqueness check prior to issuing the command, by consulting a lightweight query model containing the desired constraint.